# DistinctBy not working in C#/ Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, generics

I am using DistinctBy to return a distinct list. It is somehow not accepting the method.

```
List<LastLocation> tempLast = details.DistinctBy(x => x.deviceID).ToList();
```

This was a working project a few days ago when I was using Visual Studio 2008. I migrated the project to Framework 4.0 and I am currently using Visual Studio 2012 and suddenly this has started causing problems.
Below is the list of Namespaces being used and assemblies referenced.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using COMMON;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: By "Not accepting" the method you actually mean, that you cannot compile it. This is, because you may have removed a required using statement, e.g.:
`using System.Linq;`
Which "imports" the extension methods. I guess your first problem with the includes has something to do with the project settings or something, or just fix your references to the correct assemblies. WIthout more information it is hard to tell what the exact problem is

Comment: DistinctBy is not part of standard Linq. Either use GroupBy + First or get an implementation from Morelinq

Comment: Then why it worked in VS2008 ??

Comment: "this has started causing problems" That's too vague. We can't answer this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Edit: 3 January 2023***

.NET 6 onwards has [DistinctBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0) available out of the box. Assuming you're on the LTS versions of .NET I'd recommend using this approach rather than the one below.

***Old Answer***

You do not need to install any `Nuget` package to handle `DistinctBy` requests. Simply adding the below line of code will point it at one of the many pre-installed references.

```cs
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;
```

From there add `.DistinctBy(d => d.Name)` at the end of any returned collection, similar to the below example.

```cs
var foo = _repository.GetList().DistinctBy(d => d.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

`DistincyBy` is provided through [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) and not part of the framework. Check you've got MoreLinq installed and referenced.

Comment: From where can i refernce MoreLinq??

Comment: You can install it using NuGet (right click on solution/project and choose Manage Packages).

Comment: +1 Thank you..! It says that I need to wait for 7 minutes to mark it as an answer.. :)

Comment: i wonder why this did not happen in VS 2008.. Surprising.. :/

Answer (score 3):

DistinctBy is not a part of Linq. Maybe you are missing a NuGet package for [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) or you did not include your own extension methods.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
details.Select(x => x.deviceID).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: -1: This is not equivalent. It returns only the deviceID, not the whole location. An equivalent query would be `details.GroupBy(x => x.deviceID).Select(x => x.First()).ToList()`